# I hosted my site from Digital Ocean, but when I logged into WordPress, it says my username is not registered

Tags: wordpress, hosting, digital-ocean

I created my site in localhost (wordpress) and then migrated the entire site and then hosted it from digital ocean.

At first, I could log into wordpress but when I logged out once and tried to log in, it said my username was not registered.

Could anyone please help me with this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aPBa.png)

Comment: have you added the same database which you have previously?

Comment: @prajwal Can you try with your email address?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would recommend is that you look through your emails to see if you received some sort of confirmation when you first set up your WordPress site. You should have, but it’s possible that it was inadvertently overlooked, deleted, or even filtered as spam.

If you’re unable to find that email, you might log into your web hosting control panel to see if there is a link or other way to log into your WordPress admin directly from your web hosting control panel.

First, you need to log in to the control panel dashboard of your WordPress hosting account. Next, you need to navigate to the Databases section where you can click on the phpMyAdmin icon.

You will now see the list of tables in your WordPress database.

- Open the users table
- Click the users table in the menu to the left. The table can have
  different prefixes, in this example it is www_.
- Locate the user for which you want to change the password and click
  Edit.
- Next to user_pass choose MD5 from the drop down menu under Function.
- Under Value replace the current encrypted password with the new password. You can type normal text, it will be encrypted after saving.
- Click Go to save your changes.

Your new password has been saved and encrypted. It can now be used to login to WordPress.